# What is the alternative of AuthCacheValue and AuthCacheImpl in Java11

Tags: java, java-11, com.sun.net.httpserver

AuthCacheValue and AuthCacheImpl were present in sun.net package till jdk 1.8
But now while trying to use the same in jdk 11, it seems the package is no longer visible. Any leads would be highly appreciated if someone can suggest what exactly is the alternative of it or how this can be achieved

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.